# Why stops arduino with running after approx 1 week?

Tags: arduino, webrequest, ethernet

This is for a small home automation system. I've got a arduino uno with an ethernet shield. This arduino handles a request coming from a other website, and sets a pin high for 1.5 seconds. then our gate or fence opens or closes.

This system works great for approximately one week. then I have to manually reset the arduino, and it work for another week.

Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEE };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,54);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(8080);

//variables for clicking

bool gateClick = false;
bool fenceClick = false;
long time = 0;
boolean isBusy = false;


void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);



  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);

  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean newData = false;
String request = "";
while (client.connected()) {

  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    request += c;
    newData = true;

  }
  if (newData) {
    // send a standard http response header
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
    client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
    //client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
    client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    client.println();
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    client.println("<html>");


    //Request is always: "value(abc)?".
    //  a is always 2,
    //  b: 1 = fence, 2 = gate,
    //  c: 0 of 1 open of close, regular push button, not important
    if (request.indexOf("value(210)?") != -1 || request.indexOf("value(211)?") != -1)
    {
      client.println("Ok");
      fenceClick = true;
    }
    else if (request.indexOf("value(220)?") != -1 || request.indexOf("value(220)?") != -1)
    {
      client.println("Ok");
      gateClick = true;

    }

    else
    {
      client.println("not in use");
    }


    client.println("</html>");
    newData = false;
    break;
  }

}
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }


  //setting pin high or low
  //There only can be one pin high at the same time, hardware requires that

  //when any pin is high
  if(isBusy == true)
  {
    //when any pin is high for more than 1500 millis, make it all low
    if(millis() - time > 1500 || millis() - time <0)
    {

      digitalWrite(7, LOW);//gate

      digitalWrite(6, LOW);//fence

      Serial.println("All low");

      isBusy = false;
    }
  }
  else
    //when all pins are low, check if there's any that must be high
  {

    if( gateClick == true)
    {
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      time = millis();
  isBusy = true;
  gateClick = false;
  Serial.println("Gate high");


}
else if( fenceClick == true)
{
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  time = millis();
  isBusy = true;
  fenceClick = false;
  Serial.println("fence high");

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that `millis()` returns `unsigned long` but you save it in `long`. Still this should only cause problems after about 24 days.

Comment: You could add more `Serial.print` commands and then see what is last message you get before it stops working, to try to find exact place which causes problem.

Comment: Please explain what happens when you "have to reset". What message is the last? Also try to print a `millis()` time with each message.

Comment: with resetting, I mean pushing the reset button or removing the power and plugging it back in.
I placed more 'Serial.print' in the code, and I'm now waiting until it blocks again.

But an other idea. normally the USB port is not connected to the computer. And the 'Serial.print' is still in the code from when I was debugging. Is it possible it locks because it cannot send the info to the usb, because there's a buffer that runs full?

Comment: No, my question was "how do you understand that reset is needed?". P.S.: use user tags like @SibrechtGoudsmedt in your comments when you want the user to be notified about it. Otherwise he will not find it.

Comment: @ilotXXI, When a request comes in, and it is a request to open the gate or fence, he answers with "ok", otherwise with "not in use".
But when the arduino hangs, he does not respond anymore and the gate or fence doesn't react anymore.
Because I didn't connect it to the computer, I do not know the last message y. I now added comments and let it run for a night, connected to the computer, but it is still running without hanging... I'll probably  have to wait a bit longer?
I'm pretty new here, so I didn't know about the tags, but thanks.

Comment: Don't know what it is. Possible sources of hang are `while` loops (do they always finish?). Try to add debug outputs to them, look out messages after hang. It also may be a hardware problem, e.g. unstable power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing all the "Serial" Lines. It looks like a buffer ran full and the arduino stops running. It is running good for about a couple of months.